# Website: Facebook share link image not being recognized

Tags: html, facebook, web, share, meta

This problem has been haunting me for more then 24 working hours now.  My site "ghostwriter.co.nf" has a facebook share bar to the right of the page.  When doing a facebook share no image shows as a thumbnail.  Now i have done some research on this site and others which have lead me to

1. create meta tags:

   meta property="og:title" content="Guest Writer" />

   meta property="og:type" content="website" />

   meta property="og:url" content="http://ghostwriter.co.nf" />

   meta property="og:image" content="http://ghostwriter.co.nf/image/bannergw4med.jpg" />

   meta property="og:site_name" content="Guest Writer" />
2. Used the facebook linter tool to update the facebook cashe

Neither have worked and when i run the linter tool i get the message -
**"Unable to download og:image:
The image referenced by the url of og:image tag could not be downloaded."**

Can someone look at my very simple code and see if they can help me out thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: if you try to access the url to the image directry from the browser, you get a php error...

Comment: No, if i access the picture from browser it shows up fine

Comment: http://i48.tinypic.com/mkiwdf.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Even due you say you can access the image, i guess you do it localy, and then you have all the permissions needed.
on a remote request (like me asking for the image) you get a php permission error like in this screenshot i did:

http://i48.tinypic.com/mkiwdf.jpg

give the right permissions to the anonymous iis/apachi user and everything should be fine.

Comment: ok i see that message how to i change the permissions of that file?

Comment: By the way im using a free web host biz.nf could that be an issue?

Comment: no, i still believe you need to set permissions on the file and/or folders.

Comment: you should have some kind of a control panel in the webhost, there you need to find a File Manager, and apply read permissions (i guess)